# Replicate the SVG stroke-dasharray using only HTML and SCSS (or CSS)

Tags: css, svg, sass, frontend

I'm trying to create the classic circle loader similar to this example
https://dribbble.com/shots/1918018-Circle-Loading-Animation

So, I know that is possible to use an SVG with stroke-dasharray and sure it will be the easy way.
By the way, I'm asking if there is another way to do that using only the SCSS (or CSS).

My goal is to replicate that kind of loader, without add any SVG to the HTML file.

Thank you!

Comment: You could also use an animated svg as the background of your loader if you don't want any extra html.

Comment: It's `stroke-dashoffset` not stroke-offset. And you'll need also a `stroke-dasharray`. You can use this in CSS. I would like to know why you don't want to use this technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with the minimum `stroke-dashoffset` being about 25% of the circle circumference, you can do it as follows.

Basically you have four square child elements. Each has a circular border covering one side of the square (ie 25% of the circumference).  These child elements all overlap. Then you rotate each child with slightly different animation start times.

```css
.lds-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.lds-ring div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}
@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-ring">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Source: https://loading.io/css/

Comment: awesome, I was looking for something similar! Thank you!